# Wordpress add_admin_page not working even parameters are correct?

Tags: plugin-development, theme-development

```
function Y_add_admin_page(){
add_menu_page('Y-07 Theme Options','Y-07','mange_options','y-admin','Y_admin_create','',110); 

    }
 add_action('admin_menu','Y_add_admin_page');
```

I had used is_admin function it is returning false even I am an adminstrator

Comment: `is_admin()` function doesn't check if you are admin, it checks if the page you are visiting is a `wp-admin` page.

Comment: please edit your question to explain what is "not working"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please try this

```
add_action('admin_menu','Y_add_admin_page');

function Y_add_admin_page(){

    add_menu_page(
          'Y-07 Theme Options'
        , 'Y-07'
        , 'manage_options'
        , 'y-admin'
        , 'Y_admin_create'
        , ''
        , 110
    );

}
```

Comment: @ kamlesh pal Not Working

Comment: i have tried this in my local setup of WordPress and now i can see the menu in left side of my wordpress cms

Comment: And also you have to create Y_admin_create this function to show what you want after click

Comment: Created call back function but no use

Comment: I had checked i am logged in and shows i am adminstrator but when i test in php file is_admin returns false